# Is it safe to empty the tmp folder from Jboss/Server/default?

Tags: jboss, jboss5.x

I'm using JBoss 5.1.0.GA, I notticed the tmp folder at: server/default/tmp is mora than 1GB big.

Can I safely delete all the files in it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, it is safe to delete `server/default/tmp`, as well as `server/default/work`.

---

http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/getting_started/v5/html/tour.html

Search for "run -c myconfig" on that page; the relevant info is immediately below. Unfortunately I can't get you a direct link to that section of the page, sorry!

Comment: is it safe to delete the server/default/data folder if i plan to restart the instance?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's safe to delete the **Temp** Folder, **work**, as well as **log** folder from the location `server/default/`.

It ensures you are free of any shadow copy of your previous project.